# Node JS chat server

Tags: javascript, node.js

Trying to figure out how to get this code to work when running it with node. I believe it was made to run in telnet but would like to run it through node.

right now it will run but the error I run into is when I try to send a message nothing is sent.

It will show the users as they join the chat but won't show messages if anyone types a message.

server.js below

```
let net = require('net');
let sockets = [];
let port = 2708;
let guestId = 0;

let server = net.createServer(function(socket) {
    // Increment
    guestId++;

    socket.nickname = "Guest" + guestId;
    let userName = socket.nickname;

    sockets.push(socket);

    // Log it to the server output
    console.log(userName + ' joined this chat.');

    // Welcome user to the socket
    socket.write("Welcome to the chat!\n");

    // Broadcast to others excluding this socket
    broadcast(userName, userName + ' joined this chat.\n');

    socket.on('adduser',function(n){
        console.log("UserName: " + n);
        userName = n;
    });


    // When client sends data
    socket.on('data', function(data) {

        let message = clientName + '> ' + data.toString();

        broadcast(clientName, message);

        // Log it to the server output
        process.stdout.write(message);
    });


    // When client leaves
    socket.on('end', function() {

        let message = clientName + ' left this chat\n';

        // Log it to the server output
        process.stdout.write(message);

        // Remove client from socket array
        removeSocket(socket);

        // Notify all clients
        broadcast(clientName, message);
    });


    // When socket gets errors
    socket.on('error', function(error) {

        console.log('Socket got problems: ', error.message);

    });
});


// Broadcast to others, excluding the sender
function broadcast(from, message) {

    // If there are no sockets, then don't broadcast any messages
    if (sockets.length === 0) {
        process.stdout.write('Everyone left the chat');
        return;
    }

    // If there are clients remaining then broadcast message
    sockets.forEach(function(socket, index, array){
        // Dont send any messages to the sender
        if(socket.nickname === from) return;

        socket.write(message);

    });

};

// Remove disconnected client from sockets array
function removeSocket(socket) {

    sockets.splice(sockets.indexOf(socket), 1);

};


// Listening for any problems with the server
server.on('error', function(error) {

    console.log("So we got problems!", error.message);

});

// Listen for a port to telnet to
// then in the terminal just run 'telnet localhost [port]'
server.listen(port, function() {

    console.log("Server listening at http://localhost:" + port);

});
```

client.js below

```
let net = require('net');
let client = new net.Socket();

client.connect(2708, '127.0.0.1',function(){
    console.log("Client Connected!\n");
    client.emit('adduser',"UserName");
});

client.on('data',function(data){
    console.log(""+data);
});

client.on('close', function() {
    console.log('Connection closed');
});
```

Comment: `Net` is a built in package of `Node's` there is documentation at https://nodejs.org/api/net.html